Node not deleted entirely, as there seems to be garbage a.k.a null value left
I am working on a library management system for my class, we were asked to create a program for it. In the Book Title Class, I have a function to delete a Book based on the book number, which is this code below.
void xoaSachByMaSach(NodeSach*& head, char* maSach) {

    if (head == nullptr) return;

    
    if (strcmp(head->sach.MASACH, maSach) == 0) {
        NodeSach* temp = head;
        head = head->next; 

        
        strcpy(temp->sach.MASACH, "");
        strcpy(temp->sach.vitri, "");
        temp->sach.trangthai = -1; 

        delete temp; 
        temp = nullptr;  
        return;
    }


    NodeSach* current = head;
    while (current->next != nullptr && strcmp(current->next->sach.MASACH, maSach) != 0) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current->next != nullptr) {
        NodeSach* temp = current->next;
        current->next = temp->next; 

        
        strcpy(temp->sach.MASACH, "");
        strcpy(temp->sach.vitri, "");
        temp->sach.trangthai = -1;  

        delete temp; 
        temp = nullptr;  
    }
}

I was expecting it to work in this way. First, I try to get the node of the book.
NodeSach* nodeSelect = GetNodeSach(DSDS.nodes[curDauSach]->First, 10 * (curPageSach - 1) + curSach);

NodeSach* GetNodeSach(NodeSach* First, int position) {
    NodeSach* node = First;
    for (int i = 0; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
        if (i == position) break;
        ++i;
    }
    return node;
}

I then get the Book class of the current pointed book (I build the graphics and UI in BGI graphics.h).
Sach sach(edHieuChinhMaSach.content, edHieuChinhTrangThaiSach.toInt(), edHieuChinhViTriSach.content);

I then delete the Book by calling the xoaSachByMaSach like this.
xoaSachByMaSach(nodeSelect, sach.MASACH);

The thing is, I was expecting it to work and the delete the book (the whole Book Title thing is working as a Single Linked List) but it seems like it goes something wrong. When I use other code to draw the text, it seems like it is not entirely deleted, as there seems to be some kind of null value left, thus trigger Visual Studio 2022 debugging system to stop. I can't seem to figure out what exactly is the error, given that on a separate test to ensure that the code was done correctly, it run pretty much alright.
Any help will be appreciated.

Assuming you think that temp = nullptr will modify any other pointer, it will not. That will only assign to the local variabler temp, which will go out of scope and end its life when the block ends, making the assignment irrelevant.

Other than that, once you have passed a pointer to delete, you can not dereference that pointer again. Doing that will lead to undefined behavior.

And my usual comment when it comes to things like linked lists: Use pencil and paper first to figure out all your operations. Then if there's a problem, step through the code line by line in a debugger, while at the same time draw, erase and redraw all operations you do in the code on a different paper. Compare to your first paper, does it do what you expect it to do? When and where does it go wrong?

On a totally different note, why are you making your own list? Is this a class (or similar) exercise? If not, then use std::vector as container. And use std::string for all strings. And standard algorithms whenever possible.

The thing is, the teacher asked us to write our own thing. He does not allow using the standard library, so pretty much we have to build our own on stuffs like you just mentioned.

How do you check for this "not quite deleted" node? If you access values in an object after it was deleted then you will naturally see old or garbage values - this is undefined. Don't access objects after you deleted them. It is more efficient for programs to just remove the pointer to the allocated memory, but not actually reset the memory to all 0s, if that's what you're asking. Also please see How do I ask and answer homework questions?

He does not allow using the standard library -- But you are using strcmp, which is part of the standard library.  I think you went overboard with the "not able to use the standard library" when it comes to using std::string.  You still have to write the guts of the linked list anyway, regardless of whether you use std::string or not.  Thus it would have made your code a lot easier if you used std::string instead of char arrays and (standard library again) strcmp and strcpy.

Also, what is temp->sach?  Whatever it is, does this make sense to change the temp internals, and you are going to delete it anyway?  I'm referring to this: strcpy(temp->sach.MASACH, ""); strcpy(temp->sach.vitri, "");temp->sach.trangthai = -1; delete temp;.  Unless I'm missing something, why are you going through the motions of setting things in temp, when ultimately it will be deleted?

Nothing says that a deleted object has to go away immediately. It is simiilar to thowing a piece of paper in the bin - you might still be able to read the text until someone empties the bin.

This is a god-awful C++ course. In the Data Structures class I used to teach I obviously had students write their own linked lists and etc., but they were proper classes and and not leftovers from C.

Often it's worth your time to use the forbidden library stuff during development so you can test other parts of the program against known-good implementations. If you can get the business logic of the program working with a library container, you can later swap out the container with your own implementation and not have to test two complicated bits of code at once.

If you're not allowed to use the Standard Library, what's the justification for strcmp(), et. al.?

@sweenish when I was a younger man, I went back to school during the Dot Crash and had to formally learn Java. It was entertaining looking at the assignments and seeing the echoes of past C and Pascal versions of the course colouring the Java course. I pointed it out to an even older programmer who snickered and then highlighted signatures of Fortran and COBOL in how the assignment was specified. Programming courses seem to be Object-Oriented. Lot of inheritance going on.

In your code, delete temp; temp = nullptr;  then temp ceases to exist.   The assignment to nullptr achieves nothing.   And delete temp typically does not change the value of temp (it affects what temp points at, not the value of temp itself).       Also, modifying the object temp points at before deleting it (strcpy(temp->sach.MASACH, ""); strcpy(temp->sach.vitri, ""); temp->sach.trangthai = -1; delete temp; also is mostly meaningless  (if you need to counter something that is directly reading raw memory used by your program, you're in the realm of undefined behaviour anyway)

"garbage a.k.a null value" -- Garbage values are usually not null, and null values are often not garbage. Neither is known as the other ("a.k.a." == "also known as"). Which is it? Are you seeing a null (zero) value or some strange value that bears no resemblance to the data you've been working with (a.k.a. a garbage value)?

"When I use other code to draw the text," -- Maybe this "other code" is what's at fault. One reason a [mre] should be complete enough to reproduce the problem is that people often misdiagnose where the problem is. Keep it short, and dummy up what you can (maybe use a single integer as data instead of a string), but also make your code complete enough so that someone can copy-compile-run it to see the problem. A main function and output would be good. Input is less good (hardcode data instead).
